# C#: After running program and the input is answered with an if statement, how do i get the program to keep asking the question?

Tags: c#, string, class, if-statement, static

I asked a question in the WriteLine form that requires a numbered input, converted it to an int, used that int in an if-else, and I want the question to be re-asked afterward. Any idea?

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("What hour is it?: ");
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (hour > 0 && hour < 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's morning.");
}

if (hour > 12 && hour < 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's evening.");
}
else if (hour > 18 && hour < 24)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's night.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming to stack overflow. This is a great platform to have your questions answered however this question can be quickly answered with a proper google search or even a search here on the site. However to help provide a good learning experience for the logic I'll provide a pseudo-code answer followed by code to give you a solid understanding.

Comment: Fair warning, people here are not very receptive to questions that have easily found answers. This question is a fundamental programming concept, and if you don't want a question ban, I recommend you do your due diligence in searching for a solution before posing a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are three primary ways to loop in C#

> - while ( someCond is true or false)
> - for ( int someVar is 0 and it's less than or greater than or equal to some var)
> - foreach (someObj in someObjects)

Your code is as follows, in pseudocode.

> - **While** the user is doing something
> - Ask a question
> - Record the answer
> - Compare it to your possible conditions
> - Output a response.

Notice a key-word there in your pseudo-code. Make use of that. When learning it's imperative to take the time to understand every little tiny detail and writing it out in plain language will help you to identify those key-words.

#### Code Snippet

```
bool someBool = false;
while(!someBool)
{
    //Ask A question
    //Record an answer.
    //Check Condition
    if (true)
       {
           //Do something
           someBool = true;
       }
    else 
       {
           //Do something else.
           //Keep `someBool` set to false
       }
}
```

Now it's up to you to implement your code where it goes to make it function exactly how you want it to function, your conditionals, where it breaks, etc.